# Cookie Regular Expression in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, expression

Im trying to find the easiest way to convert a string containing 3 cookies into 3 seperate variables each containing one cookie.

I was trying regular expression but ive tried so many different approaches I'm kinda lost now... Any suggestions on an approach that would be best? or confirmation that re.match is the way to go?(I read somewhere that this gets the result into groups?)

```
ASP.NET_SessionId=dqxmhmiDDsraoy4znfohxuk5; ASP.NET_SessionComm=ohitdbrqaaoy4znfohitdS9; SIDPCookie=yDsraavwmhmioi55a2litd55;
```

into

```
a= 'ASP.NET_SessionId=dqxmhmiDDsraoy4znfohxuk5;' 
b= 'ASP.NET_SessionComm=ohitdbrqaaoy4znfohitdS9;' 
c= 'figCookie=yDsraavwmhmioi55a2litd55;'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
In [1]: s = "ASP.NET_SessionId=dqxmhmiDDsraoy4znfohxuk5; ASP.NET_SessionComm=ohitdbrqaaoy4znfohitdS9; SIDPCookie=yDsraavwmhmioi55a2litd55;"

In [2]: a, b, c = s.split()

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 'ASP.NET_SessionId=dqxmhmiDDsraoy4znfohxuk5;'

In [4]: b
Out[4]: 'ASP.NET_SessionComm=ohitdbrqaaoy4znfohitdS9;'

In [5]: c
Out[5]: 'SIDPCookie=yDsraavwmhmioi55a2litd55;'
```

Comment: OMG, I cant believe i didn't think of this! Thanks!!